# Querybuilder in QGIS-->select features in a shp-file, which touch others

Tags: qgis, definition-query

I have a ESRI-shp-file called veg.shp and the field BYKP. Is it possible to make a query within the querybuilder and select all polygons with the beginning attriubte "F" and the second condition where they touch all polygons with the beginning attriubte "O" in the field "BYKP"

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with a single selection for a shape-file as the standard Qgis SQL does not have the ST_Touches Function as far as i know. But there are other ways.

First(recommended):

Save as a Spatial-Lite layer and then use the ST_Touches together with LIKE 'F%' AND LIKE 'O%'.

Second:

Add your Layer twice and select the F-Features in one and the O-Features in the second. Then use a spatial query with touches and the the option to use selected features only. You need to this for both Layers and merge the output.